# MySQL Unite Two Tables

Tags: mysql, backup-restoration

Situation: after crash (or hack, I'm not still sure) some in table vB_users disappeared.
I have march backup of that table, but since that time there were new records.
Is there a fast way to add all the rows from crashed table to the backup table and rewrite the existing rows? I mean, unite them, but the crashed version shoul have the priority over old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your crashed table is in a DB called current, your restored backup is in a DB called backup, and there's a primary key called id:

```
create table current.tempUsers as select * from backup.vB_users ub where not exists (select 1 from current.vB_Users uc where uc.id = ub.id);

insert into current.vB_users select * from current.tempUsers; 

drop table current.tempUsers;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'uc.id' in 'where clause' , what the ub and uc basically?

Comment: ub and uc are just aliases for backup.vB_users and current.vB_users to save typing. Is there actually an "id" column?

Answer (score 1):

Rename the crashed table, restore the backup (from MARCH?  ouch), rename *that* one, create a new table with the old name, then do something like:

```
INSERT INTO vB_users SELECT * FROM crashed_table UNION SELECT * FROM restored_table;
```

This might not work quite right in the event of records that have the same PK but different values; you can probably do some sneaky things to fix that up.